# R cut function with a specified breakpoint

Tags: r

I have this vector

```
ages <- c(17, 18, 16, 20, 22, 23)
```

and i need to  create a factor that has levels Minor or Adult where any observation greater than or equal to 18 qualifies as an adult.

I tried this:

```
ages<-cut(ages, breaks=2, labels=c('Minor', 'Adult'))
```

but it still labels 18 as Minor but it should be Adult
How can i speciyf break threshold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't need `cut` for only two groups

```
factor(c('Minor', 'Adult')[(ages  > 17) + 1])
#[1] Minor Adult Minor Adult Adult Adult
#Levels: Adult Minor
```

---

Also, with `cut`, if we don't specify the interval and only to cut into 2 groups, the interval will be different than the chosen one of 18.  So, we pass a numeric `vector` of cut points instead of the number of cuts to be made and specify the `labels` accordingly

```
cut(ages, c(-Inf,17, Inf), labels = c('Minor', 'Adult'))
#[1] Minor Adult Minor Adult Adult Adult
#Levels: Minor Adult
```

The reason why OP's code is labelling incorrectly is based on the groupings

```
cut(ages, 2)
#[1] (16,19.5] (16,19.5] (16,19.5] (19.5,23] (19.5,23] (19.5,23]
#Levels: (16,19.5] (19.5,23]
```

Here, the cut point is 19.5 instead of 18

How it is calculating the `breaks` can be determined if we check the function

Comment: In the second chunk of code you provided, it splits on 17 right? But then 17.5 will be treated as adult. I like this way of splitting but what about making it split from -inf to 18(excluding) for 'minors' and then from 18(including) to inf as 'adults'?

Comment: @AlexT I thought it is an integer value.  You can change the split values to 17.9 or so i.e. `cut(c(ages, 17.9), c(-Inf,17.9, Inf), labels = c('Minor', 'Adult'))#
[1] Minor Adult Minor Adult Adult Adult Minor`

Comment: Ah ok, I was thinking if there was a way to explicitly state that 18 and above.

Comment: @AlexT  There are arguments in `cut` where you can specify it i.e. `cut(c(ages, 17.9), c(-Inf,18, Inf), labels = c('Minor', 'Adult'), right = FALSE)`